# Соц сети и облачные технологии?

Tags: веб-программирование, облако

В определении облачной технологии сказано

> «Облачная обработка данных — это
> парадигма, в рамках которой информация
> постоянно хранится на серверах в
> интернет и временно кэшируется на
> клиентской стороне, например, на
> персональных компьютерах, игровых
> приставках, ноутбуках, смартфонах и т.
> д.»

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю, что тогда получается, что любая соц. сеть и любой сайт хранящий информацию о пользователе, в том числе и ХэшКод, тоже по сути может считаться облачной технологией?

Comment: В "Облачных технологиях" гораздо важнее то, что сам процесс обработки информации происходит на сервере и скрыт от пользователя (вроде как в облаке).
Снаружи сложную систему видно совсем иначе нежели изнутри.

Comment: Когда мы продаем облачные технологии, то подразумеваем, что информация и вычисления не привязаны к *конкретному железу* в значительно большей степени, чем когда говорим о серверных технологиях.

Безусловно, софт вместе с IP и логическими дисками может переехать с одной железяки на другую и не в традиционных системах. Но, когда говорим об облаках, то переезд сервиса это обычное и действительно незаметное (так должно быть :)) для заказчика услуги явление.

Скажу так, имея дело с облаком, заказчик *в самом деле* не должен знать, в какой среде он в данный момент работает.

Answer (score 2):

формально - да, может. Но в действительности вряд ли. На практике под облачными сервисами подразумеваются технологии, которые берут на себя "клиентские" вычисления. Например, облачные IDE, которые не надо устанавливать на локальной машине, и которыми можно пользоваться из браузера, или облачные игровые сервисы, которые не требуют наличия диска с игрой и мощного железа. Так вот обычные сайты под это определение не подпадают, поскольку никаких традиционно-клиентских вычислений они на себя не берут. 
   Впрочем, соцсети, хранящие контент на серверах, и предоставляющие его пользователю, несколько ближе к такому определению облачных сервисов. Хотя, вряд ли вообще имеет смысл их относить  в эту категорию, поскольку у них совершенно иная специфика.

А вообще вопрос явно не по теме, так как к программированию отношения не имеет